# Filtering multiple data in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to retrieve multiple value based on their `data` value below. Currently what I did is I've been using `for loop` below but it only retrieve one value and I want to update based on the `looping result`.It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

```
gallery_photos table. I want to update `Person tbl path when the value of photos column in gallery_photos and path person table equals
```

[image]

*Person* tbl

[image]

```
@login_required(login_url='log_permission')
def archive_folder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_id = request.POST.get('id')  #single value only example we have: 6

        data = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = idd) # multiple value example we have 3 rows

        for sample in data :
            viewing= sample.photos # I want to retrieve those three rows based on their photos column value in database
            Person.objects.filter(path = viewing).update(path=None)
    return JsonResponse({'data': 'success'})
```

*models.py*

```
class folder_info(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
     date_upload = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     class Meta:
         db_table = "folder_info"

class gallery_photos(models.Model):
    gallery_info_id = models.IntegerField()
    photos = models.FileField(upload_to='Photos/', unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gallery_photos'

class Person(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you add model relation in this question? `gallery_photos`, `Person`...

Comment: So you are trying to get `id` from the url, then get all `gallery_photo` having that `id`, put them into `data`, and each `sample` is an array of `photo`?

Comment: @Ngoc Pham thanks for your response I added more details above, but in summary I just want to display this all data multiple   `data = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = idd)`   that has a value under `photos` column in my database

Comment: @Hùng H. - UIT thanks for your response I added more details , Yes that's exactly what I mean but the problem is how can I read these data from photos column   `data = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = idd)`  I tried for loop but it only returns one value instead of multiple value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this. `values_list` return `array` of `photos`, and you can use it for filter `in` for update all of this. `print` for debug check what you get before update, can remove if you don't use.

```
def archive_folder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_id = request.POST.get('id')

        photos_data = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = data_id).values_list("photos", flat=True)

        print(photos_data)
        Person.objects.filter(path__in = photos_data).update(path=None)
    return JsonResponse({'data': 'success'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm confused I also want to delete multiple column in my gallery_photos ? Im trying to used this `delete_list = gallery_photos.objects.get(gallery_info_id = data_id).delete()`  error says ` returned more than one gallery_photos`

Comment: First, my answer can resolve your problem? 
Second: better one thread only resolve one problem. 
For your question: you must use `filter(id=id).delete()` for use function `delete()`.

Comment: Yes it solve my problem thank you but in relation to my problem I want also to delete those gallery_photo based on the Id given but error says it returned more than one gallery_photos

Comment: yeah, function `get()` raise exeption if found 2 objects. Check your database for sure your database not wrong.

Comment: I think there's no wrong about my database I just want to delete all data that equals to my ID, either more than one data or not  it is possible? like what you did previously

Comment: you can try `gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = data_id).delete()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `django-filter` package. It supports multiple filters in a single query.

You can also use the [Imagine smart compiler](https://www.imagine.ai) that will generate the code for your app including this multiple-field filters.
It will also simplify your permissions checking code.
Your model is simple enough, that you should not have to do anything custom. The entire code base and tests should be generateable using the Imagine compiler.